# Systemd service ask password

Tags: mount, systemd, cifs

I am trying to setup a systemd service that allows users to mount a CIFS share. This is what I got:

**mount_cifs@.service**

```
[Unit]
Description=Mount CIFS share by %i
After=network-online.target
Wants=network-online.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes
ExecStartPre=/bin/mkdir -p /mnt/dir
ExecStart=/bin/mount -t cifs //remote/path /mnt/dir -o username=%i
ExecStop=/bin/umount /mnt/dir
ExecStopPost=/bin/rmdir /mnt/dir
```

However, when I run `systemctl start mount_cifs@gncs.service`, I get the following message:

```
Password for gncs@//remote/path: 
Broadcast message from root@ws (Wed 2016-10-26 21:24:56 CEST):

Password entry required for 'Password for gncs@//remote/path:' (PID 5677).
Please enter password with the systemd-tty-ask-password-agent tool!
```

How exactly am I supposed to use this tool?

Comment: After looking up the documentation for the  systemd-tty-ask-password-agent  tool, what further question do you have about how to use it?

Comment: I have read the [documentation](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-tty-ask-password-agent.html) but I don't understand which command I have to use to prompt the user for the pasword. Typing `systemd-tty-ask-password-agent` (+ options) does not do much...

Comment: Have you read the [related Q&As on the network about systemd and password prompts](http://stackexchange.com/search?q=systemd+passwords), in particular this one [systemd prompting for passwords during boot](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/77769/prompt-for-password-during-boot-with-systemd-service)

Answer (score 2):

After some reading I found out that `pwd=$(systemd-ask-password "Password:")` is at least one way of doing it. Now `systemd` no longer complains.

Comment: Can you share your complete `.service` file?

Comment: @SilleBille: I am sorry, I no longer have this service file.

Comment: I know it's been a long time, but can you share what other info did you embed on the service file? After following your post, when I start the service, it doesn't prompt the user. I'm on Fedora 28.

Comment: @gncs did you have to add that `pwd=$(systemd-ask-password "Password:")` line in your service file ?